# I started build my own blockchain based on mastering bitcoin book using git on win7 and i have a problem

Tags: blockchain, development

I started learning how to build a blockchain from Antonopoulos book using Git Bash and i have a problem.
I used commands:
 git clone github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git
cd bitcoin
git tag
git checkout v0.11.2
and when i try to use command ./autogen.sh
on the screen appear information:
./autogen.sh: line 9: autoreconf: command not found.

Where is the problem? What i do wrong? i need some libraries?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have the same problem reported in the link bellow:

https://askubuntu.com/a/490839

Just try to install autoconf. The autoreconf come with it:

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf
```

Comment: But i have to install ubuntu? cannot do on windows?

Comment: Sorry Norbert, I didn't pay attention to the picture with Windows. Actually you are executing Linux tools, but these tools came with MinGW. In this case you are using the MinGW provided by Git that don't have autoconf. Try to download and install a new copy of MinGW and chose the packages that you need. Then you can open the new MinGW and try to compile again. If you still have problems, an alternative to MinGW is Cygwin.